# How do I find photos of someone in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos, facial-recognition

I am reading [this help page](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6128838).

On this page it says the following:

> **Find photos of someone & apply a label**
>
> Use face groups to more easily search and manage your photos. After
> you apply a label to someone, you can search for them using that
> label. Note that this feature is not available in all countries.

I am in the United States, so I assume that if any country would have this feature, it would be the U.S.

> STEP 1: Find photos of someone
> On your computer, go to photos.google.com/search.
> On the box with faces, click a person's face to see photos of them. To see more people, click the arrow.

What is the "box with faces"?  The closest thing I see is "Sharing" which has two non-descript heads, which I assume is *not* what this is talking about.

> (If you don't see this box, that means this feature is not available in your country, you turned it off in settings, or you don't have any groups.)

Again, assuming that since I am in the U.S. this feature *is* available.  I went into my [settings](https://photos.google.com/settings) and "Group similar faces" is *on*.

So where is the box with faces?  How do I access this feature?

Update: I found a friend who already has a large number of images in the Google Photos, and when they click in the search bar a bar appears below it containing circles with faces in it.  However, my Google Photos just has a few images images: two images that have been there quite some time, each of which has exactly one face in it, and a number of test images I just uploaded, each of which is comprised solely of a face and nothing else.

Is there some processing delay after uploading before Google recognizes and shows faces?   Does it not deal well with pictures that are just portraits?  Or is there some minimum number of pictures that must be uploaded before any faces can be shown?